# Firestore! setting limits for documents created per day in 'Rules'

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How can I set posts 'Documents' limits that can the user create per day, for example I want to set the limit for 5 posts per day, so is there any rule something like:

```
match /Post/{id} {
    allow create: if ........
    && getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/Post/$(id))*LAST 5*".data.createdDate <= 24H....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with security rules without some of your own record-keeping.  Since security rules don't let you perform queries other than single-document `get()`, you won't be able to find out what the user has done to a collection by looking at the documents in the collection itself.  You will have to maintain some sort of per-user record *in a single document* with a summary of what they've done over time, then use that known document in a rule that would deny access if they have already exceeded the limits you set.  There is nothing very easy or straightforward abut this, and you might be better off requiring the user to go through a backed that enforces the limits instead of using security rules.